# Merge multiple CSV files with partially matching key column

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv

I have 100 `csv` files each containing 2 columns. The first is `taxonomy` and the second `counts`. Each file has about 10000 rows. The `taxonomy` data in each file is only partially shared with a total of about 50000 unique values. I need to merge these into one table where missing `taxa` in one file are assigned the value `0`. The result should be a table (`csv` or `tsv`) with 50000 rows and 101 columns.
A simplified example would be:
File 1 (`R1.csv`):

```
A,1
B,20
C,30
```

File 2 (`R2.csv`):

```
C,1
D,13
E,15
F,19
```

File 3 (`R3.csv`):

```
A,1
B,4
E,2
G,6
H,8
```

Expected result:

```
Taxa,R1,R2,R3
A,1,0,1
B,20,0,4
C,30,1,0
D,0,13,0
E,0,15,2
F,0,19,0
G,0,0,6
H,0,0,8
```

Any idea how to do this with bash scripting?

Comment: Wouldn't [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/) be more suitable and pleasant to use for this task?

Comment: I think this could be the way https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726191/195582

Answer (score 1):

I used `awk` which handling multiple files at once:

```
sed 's/,R[1-9]\+\.csv:/,/g' <(awk -v HEADER="$(printf ",%s:" R{1..3}.csv)" -F, '
    { seen[$1]=seen[$1]","FILENAME":"$2; }
    END { print HEADER; for (x in seen) print x seen[x]}' R{1..3}.csv \
|awk -F, 'NR==1{split($0,arr,/,/);next} {SEP=""; fld=1;
    for (x in arr){printf ($0 ~ arr[x])?SEP""$(fld++):",0";SEP=","};print ""}')
```

The output:

```
A,1,0,1
B,20,0,4
C,30,1,0
D,0,13,0
E,0,15,2
F,0,19,0
G,0,0,6
H,0,0,8
```

---

**Code break-down:**

```
awk -F, '{ seen[$1]=seen[$1]","FILENAME":"$2; }
    END{ print HEADER; for (x in seen) print x seen[x] }' R{1..3}.csv
```

The main part of the code that join all second column in all files into one together printing with the value belongs to which file having same first column. The `seen` here is an array name with the key as first column and value with `,FILENAME:$2` in appending mode.

In `seen[$1]=seen[$1]","FILENAME":"$2;` means print a comma `,` followed by current processing file `FILENAME` with *awk*, a colon `:` followed by second column value `$2` when it has same first column `seen[$1]=...` and append into the same key index `=seen[$1]...` and save in same key's value.

The `END` statement, *awk* executing this block in end when all records/line read, and we used a for-loop to iterate over the array *seen* and print the **key** first and the **value of the key** in next.

Will result:

```
A,R1.csv:1,R3.csv:1
B,R1.csv:20,R3.csv:4
C,R1.csv:30,R2.csv:1
D,R2.csv:13
E,R2.csv:15,R3.csv:2
F,R2.csv:19
G,R3.csv:6
H,R3.csv:8
```

OK, now we know exiting values are from which files and which files doesn't have those data. For this to filling non-existing files' data with `0`, I used shell command substitution ***to generate a header line congaing all files name*** and passed to *awk* as `HEADER` **-v**ariable:

```
awk -v HEADER="$(printf ",%s:" R{1..3}.csv)" ...
```

later we will use this `HEADER` line and fill missed files' data with `0`. Now our input is like this format:

```
$ awk -v HEADER="$(printf ",%s:" R{1..3}.csv)" -F, '
    { seen[$1]=seen[$1]","FILENAME":"$2; }
    END { print HEADER; for (x in seen) print x seen[x]}' R{1..3}.csv 
,R1.csv:,R2.csv:,R3.csv:
A,R1.csv:1,R3.csv:1
B,R1.csv:20,R3.csv:4
C,R1.csv:30,R2.csv:1
D,R2.csv:13
E,R2.csv:15,R3.csv:2
F,R2.csv:19
G,R3.csv:6
H,R3.csv:8
```

Next I used another below *awk* script to fill the non-exiting files' data with `0` which I copied from my another answer to the question ["Formatting and fill missed data based on column"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435555/72456).

```
... |awk -F, 'NR==1{split($0,arr,/,/);next} {SEP=""; fld=1;
    for (x in arr){printf ($0 ~ arr[x])?SEP""$(fld++):",0";SEP=","};print ""}'
```

In the end, the `sed 's/,R[1-9]\+\.csv:/,/g'` is used to replace the existing filess name in result with single comma `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), you could do in this way

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header put '$f=FILENAME;$f=sub($f,"\..+","")' then \
label Taxa then \
reshape -s f,2 then \
unsparsify then \
fill-empty -v 0 then \
sort-within-records then \
reorder -f Taxa *.csv
```

to get

```
Taxa,R1,R2,R3
A,1,0,1
B,20,0,4
C,30,1,0
D,0,13,0
E,0,15,2
F,0,19,0
G,0,0,6
H,0,0,8
```

Comment: I was trying by reading the data as `--ixtab --ips ,` (because the data seems to be transposed), but that did not lead me anywhere. I need to see if I can learn how to use `reshape` properly... Thanks for this.

Comment: @Kusalananda the source data are in "long" format. The great reshape verb convert from long format to wide and vice versa. It's a very important verb.

Comment: @Kusalananda I hope my answer won't be ignored. Because it looks good to me and shows that Miller is a great tool.

Comment: It's a good answer (a bit terse on explanation, though).  In the end, whether it's upvoted and/or accepted depends on others and whether they think it's useful or interesting to _them_. Ordinary, users are more used to tools like `sed` and `awk`, and will start by using these. They need a bit of extra reasoning and encouragement before venturing away from the comfort of the tools they are used to. A multi-tool like Miller might seem to be difficult to use at first, but the more examples people see, the more used to it they become. It's how `jq` has become more or less mainstream for JSON now.

Answer (score 0):

this is going to be painfull

```
 join -t, -j1 -a1 -e0 -o auto r1.csv r2.csv > r12a.csv
 join -t, -j1 -a2 -e0 -o auto r1.csv r2.csv > r12b.csv
 sort -u r12?.csv > r12.csv
 join -t, -j1 -a1 -e0 -o auto r12.csv r3.csv > r123a.csv
 join -t, -j1 -a2 -e0 -o auto r12.csv r3.csv > r123b.csv
 sort -u r123{a,b}.csv
```

- the first join print unpaired value in file x (`-ax`) with a default (`-e0`), `-o auto` tell join to print 0
- `sort -u` sort and keep unique record.

I an not sure `awk` code would be more readable.

Comment: This can be extended to process all 100 files?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to handle [CSVs on the command line](http://bconnelly.net/working-with-csvs-on-the-command-line/#extracting-columns), or the answer by Archemar. However, because of your requirements, I would advise using python. I tested out this script in python 3.5 and should solve the problem, or at least give you a good start:

```
import os,re,argparse
import csv

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='join csvs with rows of the \
        form \w+,[1-9], inserting a zero for a row label if it does not \
        exist.')
parser.add_argument('infiles', type=str, help='infile names', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

d = {}
file_idx = 0
for infile in args.infiles:
    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            parsed_line = re.match('(\w+),([0-9]+)', line)
            if not parsed_line:
                print("line {} not parsed in file {}".format(line, infile))
                continue
            if parsed_line.group(1) in d:
                d[parsed_line.group(1)].append(parsed_line.group(2))
            else:
                l = [0]*(file_idx)
                l.append(parsed_line.group(2))
                d[parsed_line.group(1)]=l
        for k in d:
            if (len(d[k]) == file_idx):
                d[k].append(0)
            if not(len(d[k]) == file_idx+1):
                print("problem with file {}, dict {}, key {}".format(f,d,k))
    file_idx = file_idx + 1

## output time
with open('results.csv','w') as csvfile:
    cwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    header = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in args.infiles]
    header.insert(0,'Taxa')
    cwriter.writerow(header)
    for k in sorted(d.keys()):
        d[k].insert(0,k)
        cwriter.writerow(d[k])
```